# How to navigate next and back in split view controller in iOS application?

Tags: ios7

I have created split view controller with two forms in IOS application.  One form consists of next button to move forward.  After that i want to move backward.

The code is:

```
 DetailViewManager *detailViewManager = (DetailViewManager*)self.splitViewController.delegate;

// Create and configure a new detail view controller appropriate for the selection.
UIViewController <SubstitutableDetailViewController> *detailViewController = nil;

SecondDetailViewController *newDetailViewController = [[SecondDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
detailViewController = newDetailViewController;
//detailViewController.title = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text;
detailViewManager.detailViewController = detailViewController;
[newDetailViewController release];
```

This code is working fine in next button but not in previous(that is already visited).

I want to see the previous state of the form also.

Any idea should be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.